# Appodeal Native ads error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, appodeal

I want o add appodeal native ads on my android project  but iam unable to add native ads its show error on AndroidMainfest file . `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"`

this tow lines show red and error how can i solve this error? 
Thanks

[error in AndroidMainfest   image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ncL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include Google Play Services lib in the project:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'